# iterating over the list which is of object type

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I have a method that is hibernate one through which I am receiving the list as shown below..

`List<abcObject> aaList= session.createCriteria(abcObject.class)`

now upon inspecting I have found that list type is of object type since criteria api return us the list of object type

Now the list am receiving is that in following fashion that is ..

```
  t_id   value
    11      3
    12      20
    14      60
    15      17    ------->(3+20+60+17 =100),here min =11 & max =15
    18      40  
    22      20
    33      40
    45      20   ---------->(40+20+40+20 =100),here min =18 & max =45
```

Now folks please advise as I have to iterate the list in such a fashion such that if count of value reaches to 100 then then there should be a seprate map get created which key would 
be min and value would be of max , now the map is of string type

```
min     max

11      15
18      45
```

and also care need to be taken such that this parameter on which division is done that is 100 should be configurable sometimes it can be set to 60 also so this division parameter is need to be configurable

so at last I want to create another map which is type of string such that min and max is of type string in that list and is stored in this fashion as shown below..

```
min     max

11      15
18      45
```

Please advise how to achieve this in java as the list is of object type .

I have tried some what this but it is not correct..

```
 final int BARRIER = 100;

    //I am going to assume there are getter methods in you abcObject and 
    //that all values are greater than 0
    List<abcObject> minMaxs = new List<abcObject>();
    int sum = 0; 
    int min = 0;
    for (abcObject obj: aaList) {
        if (sum == 0) {
            //start over, remember min
            min = obj.getT_id();
        }
        //add value to sum
        sum += obj.getValue();
        if (sum >= BARRIER) {
            //now we need to start again, remember what we got
            minMaxs.add(new abcObject(min, obj.getT_id()));
            //reset
            min = 0;
            sum = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly this is a typical [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). There are a lot of implementation examples to find.

Comment: @Andae I have already searched in google but could not able to find the exact solution

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398178/iterating-over-list-and-storing-it-contents-over-the-map/21399309#21399309

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you just need to iterate over the list and count up to `BARRIER` and find the min and max with in that bucket. If so, its not a `knapsack`.

```
int sum = 0; 
int min = 0;
int max = 0;
for (abcObject obj: aaList) {
    int tId = obj.getT_id();
    if (sum == 0) {
       //start over, remember min
       min = tId;
       max = min;
    }
    //add value to sum
    sum += obj.getValue();
    min = tId < min ? tId : min; //check if tId is lesser than min
    max = tId > max ? tId : max; //check if tId is greater than max
    if (sum >= BARRIER) {
       //now we need to start again, remember what we got
       minMaxs.add(new abcObject(min, max));
       //reset
       min = 0;
       max = min;
       sum = 0;
    }
}
```

The above method should work. All we are doing here is comparing if `min` is lesser than the current and `max` is greater than the current.